# Drag-and-drop file uploading without AJAX, synchronously in the foreground?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

I have a web site with a regular `<input type="file">` file upload, POSTing the data to the backend when the form is submitted.

I would like to progressively enhance the form so that you can drop a file from outside the browser anywhere in the viewport (not just on the file input field, as built into some browsers) to upload it.

Whether or not the form autosubmits isn't important. So if the drag-and-drop only selects the file in the file field, without starting an upload, that's fine. I don't need support for multiple files. I don't need to show upload progress, thumbnails or anything fancy.

I know there are JS libs that support drag-and-drop uploads, but they all seem to upload via AJAX. I could do that, but then I would need to modify the backend and frontend to handle upload errors, redirect and show the right messages on success and so on.

I want a progressive enhancement that doesn't require any backend changes. It should happen synchronously using the form in the page. JS is fine, as long as the upload happens "in the foreground". Synchronous AJAX would not work, of course.

Comment: In Chrome, at least, you can set the files of an file input on drop: http://jsfiddle.net/qMmPr/. Is that what you're after?

Comment: @pimvdb That's beautiful! Exactly what I wanted. And I forgot to mention that as this is for an internal service, Chrome-only is fine. If you write that as an answer (in addition to the comment), I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Although not really "synchronous" (JavaScript execution won't actually halt), you can set the files selected by `<input type="file">` programatically. In fact, such elements and dragging share their file backend implementation (`File` and `FileList` instances), so it's really straight-forward. What's more, due to both frontends using `FileList`s, dragging multiple files work just as seamlessly.

This works in Chrome (using jQuery): http://jsfiddle.net/qMmPr/.

```
$(document).on("dragover drop", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // allow dropping and don't navigate to file on drop
}).on("drop", function(e) {
    $("input[type='file']")
        .prop("files", e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files)  // put files into element
        .closest("form")
          .submit();  // autosubmit as well
});
```

Comment: @Henrik N: I now realize it doesn't like `.lnk` files on Windows. Selecting them through the input element selects the file the shortcut links to, whereas dropping a `.lnk` file gets you the `.lnk` file itself.

Comment: Not a problem for my use case. Thanks again for this!

Comment: any idea on a cross-browser solution? 
(just tested that prop() on FF16: not working)

Comment: @Bogdan D: Looks like Firefox accepts this behaviour by default when dropping files on an `input[type='file']` element (i.e. don't insert the above JavaScript code). Not sure how to route this behaviour through from the whole document, though.

Comment: @pimvdb thanks for the answer (upvoted), that behaviour is good enough for me! Entering now the peculiar world of IE10 (of course none of the above work), I'll post any useful findings...

Comment: thx so much for this, but it seems not to work for firefox and safari ?

Comment: @user1011185: Firefox supports this by default (without any code), Safari doesn't support the `drop` event it seems.

Comment: i read the commetn above about firefox, but in my case my input field is hiden and i have a `div` as dropzone. So i can't drop on the input field and when i drop in my dropzone it doesn't work on firefox

Comment: @user1011185: I'm afraid you're out of luck. `input.files = ...` doesn't do anything and `input.value = ...` throws a security exception. But you can use custom upload functionality instead of a regular form with inputs.

Comment: Strange behaviour. Safari, Chrome and Opera works on http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zlsrG, but in Firefox(version 26) the second FileList is empty without any Exception. I could not find any further informations about this topic. Can somebody explain me this behaviour?

Comment: Looks like almost the same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823395/cannot-assign-files-to-file-input-firefox-and-ie

Comment: Awesome. Works fine with dynamically added drag and drop fields. 
    let file = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
    $("input[type='file']")
        .prop("files", file);
    let imageData = file[0];    
    if(imageData){
    let preview_img = $(this).find('the image attribute');
    if (file && file[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            preview_img.attr('src', e.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file[0]);
    }
    preview_img.fadeIn();
    }
This will also add preview of the image

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @pimvdb comment, I came up with a pretty elegant solution.

Since drag and dropping on the `<input type="file" />` works, why not making it full-screen on `dragstart` to make sure the user can't miss it? Anyway he is dragging so his intentions are clear at this moment.

Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/08wbo4um

NB: unfortunately this doesn't seem to work in an `iframe`, but it does work on an actual page. You can still apprehend the behavior.

Here's the snippet:

```js
  $('input[type="file"]').on('change', function(e){
    var fileName = e.target.files[0].name;
    if (fileName) {
      $(e.target).parent().attr('data-message', fileName);
    }
  });
  
  $(document).on('drag dragstart dragend dragover dragenter dragleave drop', function(e) {
    if ($('input[type="file"]').length) {
      if (['dragover', 'dragenter'].indexOf(e.type) > -1) {
        if (window.dragTimeout)
          clearTimeout(window.dragTimeout);
        $('body').addClass('dragged');
      } else if (['dragleave', 'drop'].indexOf(e.type) > -1) {
        // Without the timeout, some dragleave events are triggered
        // when the :after appears, making it blink...
        window.dragTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
          $('body').removeClass('dragged');
        }, 100);
      }
    }
  });
```

```css
h3, p {
  text-align: center;
}

.form-group {
  margin: 30px;
}

.file-upload .form-control {
  height: 150px;
  outline: 1px dashed #ccc;
  outline-offset: -15px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.file-upload .form-control:before {
  content: "\f093";
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: 3em;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.file-upload .form-control:after {
  content: attr(data-message);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
.file-upload .form-control input[type="file"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
body.dragged .file-upload .form-control input[type="file"] {
  /* Make sure it is full screen, whatever the position absolute container */
  position: fixed;
  top: -50vh;
  bottom: -50vh;
  left: -50vw;
  right: -50vw;
  height: 200vh;
  width: 200vw;
  z-index: 10002;
}

body:after {
  content: 'You can drop the file. :-)';
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
  z-index: 10000;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: thin solid #ccc;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s ease;
}

body.dragged:after {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>Drag N Drop file upload without AJAX Demo</h3>
<p>Try drag and dropping a file. :-)</p>

<div class="form-group file-upload" required="required">
    <label class="cols-sm-2 control-label" for="document_file">File Upload</label><br>
    <div class="cols-sm-10">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-file" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <div class="form-control" data-message="Click to select file or drag n drop it here">
          <input required="required" title="Click to select file or drag n drop it here" type="file" name="document[file]" id="document_file">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It can be done by turning autoUpload to false, collecting the files in an array, then on form submit do a single ajax call with all the files together with the form data, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30566501/335396).

Comment: Thanks for this, but note "without Ajax" in the question :)

Comment: True, my approach still uses ajax, but it's only one request and in such a way that it appears as a normal submit operation for the user.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely a good solution in many cases. But as the question mentions, doing it via Ajax means you need special error handling and so on. It's not what I was after in this case but I appreciate the input all the same :)