# Cannot assign files to file input, Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript

There are two possible ways the user can initiate a file transfer: dragging and dropping to a widget, or using the multiple file input button. I like how using the multiple file input, it will replace a filename string with an intelligent "8 files selected" or whatever.

To get this, the input must be populated. Instead of actually making the xhr2 object from the drop event, I just want to pass its fileList into the input element and trigger the xhr2 via the input's "change" event.

Here's some skeleton code (jQuery used for event binding, but addListener should work the same):

```
domNode.defaultUI.on("drop", "#progOver", function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  evt.stopPropagation();
  function sendFiles() {
    var fileList = evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
    document.getElementById('files-upload').files = fileList;
  }
  if (someCondition) {
    sendFiles();
  }
});

domNode.defaultUI.on("change", '#files-upload', function(evt) {
  console.log(evt.target.files);  // fileList object in Chrome, empty (prototype) fileLIst in Firefox
});
```

I understand that the fileList object itself is read-only, and I suspect that Chrome is designed to say "Yeah, that fileList hasn't been tampered with, let's allow it" and Firefox is designed to say "Whoah the bus. Are you trying to update my lovely safe file input with some object? I don't know where that smelly object came from, DENIED!"

So the questions are two:

1. Is my above assumption correct? Is this why I can't make the input's "files" property equal to the fileList?
2. Is there an alternative way (instead of just trying to add the value to the property) of updating the input's files property? It's nice to be able to update the multiple file input node in parallel.

Comment: For security reasons, browsers are very picky when it comes to file uploads/file access.  It seems you are trying to copy the files from one `<input>` to another; you can't do that.  Instead of doing this, do what most file upload plugins do.  Hide the real `<input>` element, and just show `8 files selected` inside of a `<span>` or whatever.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, Rocket. ;) The browser knows that the user initiated the event; the security measures are taken care of by not allowing the fileList itself to be tampered with; Chrome seems to understand this, while Firefox/IE simply see an incoming object and block it. Obviously, I think Chrome's doing it right and there are no security holes in that model that I'm aware of!

Comment: Well, I guess the only issue would be if you could create your own `FileList` object.  I'd assume Chrome (and IE/Firefox) would block that.

Comment: Sure. But since the browser should be aware of the human-initated input, that I would understand. ;-) Thanks for looking, Rocket. I'll spoof the file count I guess!

Comment: That's just the first workaround I can think of since copying the `files` object obviously isn't cross-browser :)

Comment: Was this issue addressed by Firefox, or is there any current workaround at least?