# e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files not working in firefox/Safari/IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox

So, I wanted to implement simple drag and drop without using Ajax/xhr. I found the solution to this by adding this code:

```
$(document).on("dragover drop", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // allow dropping and don't navigate to file on drop
}).on("drop", function(e) {
    $("input[type='file']")
        .prop("files", e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files)  // put files into element
        .closest("form")
          .submit();  // autosubmit as well
});
```

Reference: [Drag-and-drop file uploading without AJAX, synchronously in the foreground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121589/drag-and-drop-file-uploading-without-ajax-synchronously-in-the-foreground)

It is working fine for Chrome and Opera, but as they have commented, it doesn't work in Firefox, and they have commented that Firefox treats drag and drop as default that is no code is needed, but I am unable to put it into code.

What would be the solution for Firefox?

Comment: Uhm, if Firefox does this by default, wouldn't the solution simply be to do nothing ?

Comment: Yes... i tried to do nothing for Firefox....but it wouldn't help....still not working. Am not really sure...what "nothing" is nothing :(

Comment: I just put the code, `$(document).ready(function(){ $('input').on('change', function(){ $(this).parents('form').submit; }) })` but its not working.

Comment: Ever find an answer to this? Still happening 2022. The drop functionality seems to work fine, it's the click that's getting me.